# Escape Javascript when rendering a html.erb partial from within a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, xss, render, partial

I think about if the following scenario is a security risk (XSS).
In one of my controllers I respond to a Javascript request with:

```
format.js { render :partial => "myobjects" }`
```

The myobjects partial (`_myobjects.html.erb`) is a HTML partial (that is also used by some templates) where stuff from the database is input. With jQuery I now do the following Ajax request to get the content in myobjects and replace something on the site:

```
$.get(this.href, function(data) {
  $("#myelement").html(data);
}, "script");
```

I ask myself now if this is secure.

- Do I need to explicitly do some escaping on the myobjects partial when it is used in Ajax request like above?
- Do I have to do that manually inside the partial? Or can I somehow tell that render method to do this?
- Would adding an escape_javascript call inside the partial somehow interfere when using the same partial in a normal html.erb template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought more complicated than it really is. All stuff using <%= %> is by secure by default (as HTML tags are automatically escaped in Rails >= 3). And so the above scenario is also no risk as the database content is inserted that way into the partial.